# scrapy Request callback not working when dont_filter=False

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using Scrapy 1.1.0 with Python 3.5 to scrape data from a website.
The following code is working...

```
class ImdbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "imdbFav"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.imdb.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0203166/"
    ]
    recommendRegex = re.compile(r'\/title\/([A-Za-z0-9]*)')

    def parse(self, response):
        for recommend in response.xpath('//div[@class="rec_page"]/div[@class="rec_item"]/a/@href').extract():
            mo = self.recommendRegex.search(recommend)
            recommendId = mo.group(1)
            link = "http://www.imdb.com/title/" + recommendId
            print(link)
            yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)
enter code here
```

But... I don't know why the Request callback is not called if **dont_filter=False**. 
The documentation says:

> This is used when you want to perform an identical request multiple times, to ignore the duplicates filter. Use it with care, or you will get into crawling loops.

But I am not requesting the same url. What's happening here?

Thanks friends!

Comment: Check your spider stats at the end. You probably have a non-0 `offsite/filtered`. You need to use domain names in `allowed_domains`, not URLs. So use `allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]`

Comment: Could you post your log? I've just tried it and it works fine, however your callback just redirect to the same parse method and you are pretty much stuck on infinite recursion since you do not yield any items here. I don't see any filtered requests.

Comment: hi Paul! you were right, it was just the allowed domains! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the common friend problem:

- Greg and Melissa are friends
- Melissa and John are friends
- John and Jake are friends
- Jake and Greg are friends

In your case it's about movies:

- Together suggests We are the best
- We are the best suggests Show me love
- Show me love suggests Together

When you are looking for suggestions it's bound to be a few repetitions in movies. the best way to do this is save the movie data into a database and give the suggestions by its id.